# How to query a Db link with usn/pwd provided at runtime?

Tags: oracle, dblink

Oracle Database. I have this scenario where we were using a DBLINK (type [Current User Database Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12092) ) on DB1 to DB2 which simply means the credentials user1/password1 used on the DB1 is valid for user1 on DB2.

It just so happened now that user1/password1 on DB2, password is changed to user1/password2. This is now failing as DB2 doesnot have the same password1 for the user1 as in DB1.

The way I was querying DB2 using a DBLINK on DB1 is:

```
select * from <schema>.<table>@DBLINK
```

Is there a way I can fire a static query to DB2 with the existing DBLINK and proving the new user1/password2 credentials?

Constraints:

1. Can't change the existing DBLINK configuration, no permissions
2. Can't change the existing user1/password1 on DB1. It's a master user.

Comment: Why do you think that _"... user1/password1 on DB2, password is changed to user1/password2."_. How can you see that? As far as I know a DB link is permanent?!

Comment: You can't do that. You must ask your DBA to drop and recreate the dblink. Or else, if you are on 11gR2 and up, you could alter the dblink.

Comment: @Trinimon, Can't change the existing user1/password1 on DB1. It's a master user.

Comment: I just wonder why the password should change on the database link. I cannot see any reason. Has this been done by someone else? Or does it only look like this? May be you can as your admin to write a procedure for recreation of the link - and grant execute rights ....